# control_toolbox does not use native tinyxml in fuerte

Tags: ros, tinyxml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running ros fuerte on ubunto oneiric.

I was trying to build the cyphy_serial_driver package, which depends on control_toolbox.

I got and tried to build control_toolbox using

> roslocate info control_toolbox > control_toolbox.rosinstall

> rosinstall <my_ros_dir> control_toolbox.rosinstall

> source <my_ros_dir>/setup.bash

> rosmake control_toolbox

When building control_toolbox, I got a big nasty error message, the substance of which was:

> [rospack] Error: package/stack control_toolbox depends on non-existent package tinyxml

how do I fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39836/control_toolbox-does-not-use-native-tinyxml-in-fuerte/) by [stochastic](https://answers.ros.org/users/2904/stochastic/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2012-07-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It turns out, per this link:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/tinyxml

that tinyxml used to be the name of a ros package, but now programs should just use the tinyxml system libraries.  In order to do that, several changes must be made to the control_toolbox package:

- includes of <tinyxml/tinyxml.h> or "tinyxml/tinyxml.h" need to be replaced with <tinyxml.h>
- the dependence on the tinyxml package needs to be removed from manifest.xml
- you need to tell the cmake chain that it should link against tinyxml, by adding this to your CMakeLists.txt: `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} tinyxml)`

Here is a complete diff file, which will fix these problems, and cause control_toolbox to build on fuerte.  If you put this in a file called patch.diff, you can apply this in the control_toolbox folder by doing this:

> patch -p0 -i patch.diff

> ## Index: include/control_toolbox/sinusoid.h
>
> --- include/control_toolbox/sinusoid.h    (revision 54851)
> +++ include/control_toolbox/sinusoid.h    (working copy)
> @@ -38,7 +38,7 @@
> #define SINUSOID_H_
>
> #include 
> -#include <tinyxml/tinyxml.h>
> +#include <tinyxml.h>
>
> namespace control_toolbox
> {
> Index: manifest.xml
> ===================================================================
> --- manifest.xml  (revision 54851)
> +++ manifest.xml  (working copy)
> @@ -6,7 +6,7 @@
> BSD
>
> http://ros.org/wiki/control_toolbox
>
> - 
>
> - -->
>
> ## Index: src/pid.cpp
>
> --- src/pid.cpp   (revision 54851)
> +++ src/pid.cpp   (working copy)
> @@ -35,7 +35,7 @@
> // Original version: Melonee Wise mwise@willowgarage.com
>
> #include "control_toolbox/pid.h"
> -#include "tinyxml/tinyxml.h"
> +#include <tinyxml.h>
>
> namespace control_toolbox {
>
> ## Index: CMakeLists.txt
>
> ### --- CMakeLists.txt    (revision 54851)
> +++ CMakeLists.txt    (working copy)
> @@ -11,5 +11,6 @@
> src/dither.cpp
> src/sinusoid.cpp
> )
>
> +target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} tinyxml)
> +
>
> ## rosbuild_add_executable(test_linear test/linear.cpp)

---

Originally posted by [stochastic](https://answers.ros.org/users/2904/stochastic/) with karma: 33 on 2012-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-07-26**:
Sounds like you discovered a bug. If so, please report it here: https://code.ros.org/trac/wg-ros-pkg/newticket?component=pr2_controllers&type=defect&&pr2_controllers

**Comment by [stochastic](https://answers.ros.org/users/2904/stochastic/) on 2012-07-26**:
thanks, joq, I have submitted ticket #5204: https://code.ros.org/trac/wg-ros-pkg/ticket/5204  Attached to the ticket is a file version of the patch, if that's easier for anyone else with this problem.